# Alternative to __weak references in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am using [the RSSReader project on Github](https://github.com/KieranMcGrady/RSSReader) to implement an RSS feed into my app. In KMXMLParser.h, the class defines

```
__weak id <KMXMLParserDelegate> delegate;
```

However, I am getting an error from Xcode, saying

```
/path/to/project/KMXMLParser.h:44 the current deployment target does not support automated __weak references
```

Is there any recommended way around this, without completely rewriting this class into Swift? It would be much more convenient to be able to change a single line than it would be to rewrite the entire class.

Comment: What is your current deployment target for the app?

Comment: I opened Xcode6 and made a simple app with a __weak delegate. The only way I see this error is if I set the deployment target to 4.3. If I set the deployment target to 5.0 or larger I do not see this error.

Comment: really? is it not 4.3? there are at least 2 places where a deployment target is defined. are *both* of them >= 5?

Comment: I am only using the KMXMLParser.h and .m files. I am not using the entire project itself

Comment: I am asking about your project that you are compiling in - not the RSSReader project.

Comment: The project has the deployment target set to 8.0

Comment: I converted the ivar into a property, and it got rid of the error. Not sure if this is a solution or just a beta bug.